# How to log-in to Drupal if there is no form

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-6

How can I login to a Drupal site if there is no form on the pages? When I try to access /admin it just says I don't have permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. All you need is just to access my-website.com/?q=user or my-website.com/user if you use clean urls.

Comment: This is like saying where is the button to open my laptop!